# Concepts related to compactness

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I recently took a second course in analysis and learnt about the definition of compact spaces. I was wondering if there is any significance to the following (even stronger) properties that a space $X$ may possess:

1. For every open cover of $X$, there exists a finite subcover of $X$, and this finite subcover contains a set $F$ such that $X\setminus F$ is finite.
2. Any open cover of $X$ must contain $X$ itself (thus $X$ is certainly compact and satisfies (1) also)

An example of a space with property (1) could be the subspace given by a convergent sequence. (2) suggests that there exists a *forgotten point*, by which I mean a point which is not contained in any open set except $X$ itself. Thus, no space with property (2) could be metrisable.

Do either of these concepts have any associated results or even names? Are they worth thinking about?

Comment: Property $2.$ would also imply that the space is not $T_1$ or has only one point, I think.

Comment: The requirement about a finite subcover of $X$ in 1 is superfluous. This already indicates that your properties do not have much to do with compactness. They have in fact more to do with the lack of separation properties. For instance, if $X$ satisfies the separation axiom $T_1$, property 2 cannot hold as you can consider the open cover consisting of the sets $X\setminus\{x\}$ ($x\in X$). For this reason, I doubt that these properties are of much interest.

Comment: @MartinVäth I said related to compactness because this is (only) my second course in analysis and I noted that both properties imply compactness (which is why I added the "superfluous" observation; to link to compactness). I have not yet seen the separation axioms in general, but I will have a look.

Comment: @legionwhale I did not say that they are unrelated to compactness. But these properties mean that there is a point $x\in X$ such that any neighborhood of $x$ is the whole space (or the whole space up to a finite set in case of 1). This point $x$ is in a sense “extremely non-separated”, and such things occur mainly only in pathological counterexamples which are usually excluded by hypotheses in most topological theorems.

Comment: @MartinVäth I see; thank you. If I could ask two more questions: is Hausdorff generally the level of separation used for most theorems, or do many theorems require/concern even more separated spaces?

Comment: @MartinVäth I also generally thought that Hausdorff was a "nice" property for a space to have, but with the properties above, any space with (2) is not Hausdorff and yet we can potentially say more about its continuous functions. Is there an inverse relation between separation and "niceness" or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: "or do many theorems require/concern even more separated spaces?" - It depends of course what you are examining. For real-world applications, Hausdorff is usually the minimal requirement which in many contexts is sufficient. Indeed, quite often you automatically get more by the context. For instance, compact+Hausdorff implies normal (T4).

Comment: *"any space with (2) is not Hausdorff and yet we can potentially say more about its continuous functions."* Any continuous function of a space $X$ with (2) into a $T_1$ space $Y$ is constant. (Let $x_0$ be a point whose only open neighborhood is $X$. if $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous, $y_0=f(x_0)$, then for any $y\ne y_0$ we must have $f(X)\subseteq Y\setminus\{y\}$.) For being a useful tool, we must in contrast know that there are *a lot* of continuous functions on $X$.

Comment: @MartinVäth Thanks for the help!